Daily Swiss tournament
As far as I can tell Chess.com doesn't allow a slow Swiss tournament with 2-3 days per move.
I wish to set up a chess tournament for (maybe) 10-30 colleagues at my workplace. I want it to be slow-paced, perhaps running for months. It doesn't HAVE to be a Swiss tournament, but I'm not keen on a knock-out style because participants' ratings vary a lot (I guess most wouldn't have one). It's not fun if you're out after one or two opponents, and it's meant as a social activity more than a championship.
Is there a platform built for something like this? It must be user-friendly and free for everyone, so no one is discouraged from joining.
(And why is this not possible at Chess.com?)
I'd love to hear from others with advice or ideas on what to look for. Maybe I simply don't know the right terms.

Chess.com does not appear to allow Swiss-style daily tournaments, true. I think this is likely due to the slow pace. Tournaments at 3 days per move, even with no vacation, can take years to finish. Having group-style tournaments means needing fewer rounds than Swiss-style.
One option you can consider is setting up the tournament manually rather than using the "tournament" function. If you know the rules for Swiss pairings, you should be able to pair them yourself, tell people who they need to send a challenge to, and have them report the results when they finish. This has several disadvantages (it's a lot more work for you, and you're depending on people setting up games correctly and remembering to tell you when their game finishes) but with only 30 people max it should be doable.

Thanks, I have noticed there is software to make the pairing, so I'll look into it.
